# group by repeating key

Tags: python, grouping

I need to put items in "groups" by repeating key. Meaning, items are put into one group, as long, as they have same key. If next item, has different key, new group is created and item value is put into it. Then same group is used for as long consequent items have same key.

For example having this list (where 0 index is key and 1, value):

```
lst = [('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('b', 20), ('a', 30), ('a', 40)]
```

After grouping, it should output:

```
[('a', [10]), ('b', [20, 20]), ('a', [30, 40])]
```

Currently I'm using this solution:

```
def group_by_repeating_key(lst):
    # Init group.
    groups = [(lst[0][0], [lst[0][1]])]
    for item in lst[1:]:
        last_group = groups[-1]
        group_key = last_group[0]
        item_key = item[0]
        item_value = item[1]
        if group_key == item_key:
            last_group[1].append(item_value)
        else:
            groups.append((item_key, [item_value]))
    return groups
```

But I was wondering if there is some more elegant (simpler) approach, that I could use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('b', 20), ('a', 30), ('a', 40)]
result = [(k, [i for _, i in v]) for k, v in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0])]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[('a', [10]), ('b', [20, 20]), ('a', [30, 40])]
```

Comment: Rakesh, just noticed you left a bug in your code. Modify your answer and change it to `[(k, [i for _, i in v]) for k, v in groupby(lst, lambda x: x[0])]`. By using `k[0]`, you strip key to have only one letter. It only works, if key is one symbol. If there would be keys like `a2`, `a1111` or whatever, it would strip to just `a`.

Comment: @Andrius. Thanks I missed that too.

Answer (score 0):

Following simple algorithm works:

```
lst = [('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('b', 20), ('a', 30), ('a', 40)]
outlist = []

for item in lst: 
    if len(outlist)>0 and outlist[-1][0]==item[0]:
        outlist[-1][1].append(item[1]); 
    else: 
        outlist.append((item[0], [item[1]]))

print(outlist)
```

Output:

```
[('a', [10]), ('b', [20, 20]), ('a', [30, 40])]
```